# SendGrid SMTP categories as Custom headers in phpmailer

Tags: phpmailer, sendgrid, custom-headers

How do you add SendGrid categories as customer headers using phpmailer's SMTP class?

Iv done some research and I thought this would work - but it doesn't. I'm not at all familiar with email headers and need to be pointed in the right direction.

```
$mail->addCustomHeader('category', "site #1");
```

All other mail is working fine - this method of declaring a category isn't being recognised in SendGrid. Maybe it's not even possible?

Comment: That's the correct way of adding custom headers, which suggests you've got the format wrong?

Comment: i'v gotten someone wrong, but i don't know what :P

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else wondering how to do this, I recently had to solve this issue. I did this by adding in the custom header as a complete string:

```
$mail->addCustomHeader("X-SMTPAPI: " . $sgheaders);
```

And I used `json_encode` on an array of my chosen custom headers:

```
$sgheaders = json_encode(
        array(
            "category" => array("Customer: Chosen Quote")
            ));
```

I believe you can add in as many headers as you want, so long as you do it as an associative array.